# How do I manage an array of mpz_t

Tags: c, gmp

I'm using GMP and I need an array of `mpz_t`. `sizeof(mpz_t)` gives 16, but the numbers I'm storing are considerably larger than that. Does `mpz_t` grow "in place", i. e. do I need to allocate more memory and allow for growth in-place, or does GMP allocate the space for them elsewhere and just keep references (in which case, I'm assuming, I won't have to take any special precautions.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [GNU MP 3.11 manual](http://gnu.huihoo.org/gmp-3.1.1/html_chapter/gmp_4.html) the following lines are relevant.

> GMP variables are small, containing only a couple of sizes, and pointers to allocated data. Once you have initialized a GMP variable, you don't need to worry about space allocation. All functions in GMP automatically allocate additional space when a variable does not already have enough. They do not, however, reduce the space when a smaller value is stored.

So, I guess that answers your question.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can declare an array of `mpz_t`. It's explicitly mentioned in the [GMP info pages](https://gmplib.org/manual/Nomenclature-and-Types.html#Nomenclature-and-Types):

```
mpz_t vec[20];
```

If you look into the header file, `mpz_t` holds a pointer (`_mp_d`) to an array of "limbs" that is allocated and resized dynamically via the usual means.

As for weirdness, of course:

```
typedef __mpz_struct mpz_t[1];
```

In GMP 5.1.3, an `mpz_t` is a one-element array of `__mpz_struct`, so that declaring an element works as usual. However, only a  pointer gets passed to function calls. Nice trick, actually.

Answer (score 5):

It is safe to declare an array to store a number of `mpz_t` values. According to [the GNU MP manual](http://gnu.huihoo.org/gmp-3.1.1/html_chapter/gmp_4.html):

> `mpz_t` is actually implemented as a one-element array of a certain structure type. This is why using it to declare a variable gives an object with the fields GMP needs, but then using it as a parameter passes a pointer to the object. Note that the actual contents of an `mpz_t` are for internal use only and you should not access them directly if you want your code to be compatible with future GMP releases.

Answer (score 3):

Think of it like this: if you declare a single `mtz_t` variable, the space for that variable is statically allocated by the compiler at the time of compilation. How could the size of the variable possibly change during run-time? It can't, which means that using it in an array is perfectly fine.